# Ruby on Rails - Add Scope Checking for Associated Instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5.0 app, I have two instances, Group and Group_Item.

A Group can have many Group_Items I'm wondering the best way to create a scope for Group that only selects Groups that have Group_Items.

Group.rb

```
  has_many :group_items
```

Group_Item.rb

```
  belongs_to :group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :groups_with_items, lambda { where("EXISTS (SELECT id FROM group_items WHERE group_items.group_id = groups.id)") }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to create scope without lambda is (faster one without join):

```
scope :groups_with_items, where("EXISTS(SELECT 1 from group_items where groups.id = group_items.group_id)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :groups_with_items, joins(:group_items)
end
```

Hope this will help you